# Angular Js- Is there any way to generate dynamically checkbox which are also preselected?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, dynamic, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have been wandering for two to three hours and I found chunks of relevant questions but my scenario just take a little curve. I have to generate a number of `checkboxes` which obviously would be generated through `ng-repeat`. How can I show the preselected values which I am getting from `Api`. Here is the kind of data I am receiving.

**Pre-selected data**

```
$scope.categoriess = [{"id":1,"name":"Garden Cleaning"},{"id":3,"name":"Home Cleaning"}].
```

and this is the data over which I am using `ng-repeat`.

**ng-repeat data**

```
$scope.categories = [{"id":1,"name":"Garden Cleaning"},{"id":2,"name":"Gutter Cleaning"},{"id":3,"name":"Home Cleaning"},{"id":4,"name":"Pool Cleaning"}
```

**HTML**

```
  <div ng-repeat="cats in categories">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="categoriess.id[cats.id]">
               <label>{{cats.name}}</label>
                  </div>
```

Now how would i tell `ng-repeat` to check the preselected data, plus if I want to check few more boxes they should also be checked and I want them to store in `$scope.categoriess`. I have tried a number of solution either with `ng-checked` or by make a function call in `ng-checked` I got no expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw this but i did not know how it works god it saved my life. see this [checklist-model](http://%20[1]:%20http://jsfiddle.net/iem_usman/v3k6pwrj/1/). Its so simple , no need to use ng-checked or something dynamic , preselected and gets updated easily

```
[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/iem_usman/v3k6pwrj/1/
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't u format your data to have another property, something like

```
{"id":1,"name":"Garden Cleaning", "checked": true}
```

Such way, when u iterate through the data, you can check the checkbox

```
<div ng-repeat="cats in categories">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="cats.checked">
  <label>{{cats.name}}</label>
</div>
```

Comment: thats why i posted this question, because it is what it is .

Comment: There should be some references, if you know the default categories., then u can call a function in ng-checked to match the id and return true, but not redundant though!!

Answer (score 0):

Change your html like this :

```
<div ng-repeat="cats in categories">
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="categoriess.id[cats.id]" ng-checked="isChecked(cats.id);">
   <label>{{cats.name}}</label>
</div>
```

Add this function in your controller :

```
$scope.selectedCategoriess = [{"id":1,"name":"Garden Cleaning"},{"id":3,"name":"Home Cleaning"}].

$scope.isChecked = function(id){
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.selectedCategoriess.length; i++) {
    if ($scope.selectedCategoriess[i].id == id) {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
}
```

If id is available checked value will be "true".

Comment: what does this line means ?  ng-model="categoriess.id[cats.id]"

Comment: It's in your code, I only added ng-checked function

Comment: There was an error coming on this line for (var i = 0; i < $scope.selectedCategoriess.length; i++)  length of undefined, when i set $scope.selectedCategoriess as dynamic but i handle it and fixed it, by writting if($scope.selectedCategoriess){for......}

Comment: I tried your solution before, but at that time i did not use ng-model="categoriess.id[cats.id]"

Comment: I have implemented same solution in my application, works fine.